# ECS / Fargate deregisters container in target group without any reason at 12.00AM from time to time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have AWS ECS/Fargate Service deployed with BLue/Green CodeDeploy and with AutoScaling set based on CPU threshold (1-3 instances). Every couple of days ECS stops working container without any reason and 1 minute later spawns another one. During this time app in unavailable (load balancer returns 503). In the moment when container is deregistered there aren't any alerts/errors in app/no autoscaling conditions/no deployments/no unhealthy instances in any of target groups - it's just one working container which is deregistered:

[image]

I noticed that it always happens at ~12:00AM, but not every day (every 1-3 days by average).
To me it looks like ECS is restarting containers automatically (like on heroku?) from time to time? But why it does not spawn another container before deregistering old one?

Any idea how to debug the cause of this situation?

Comment: With Fargate you have no control over underlying instances, could be that Amazon is either moving the container (task) to a different physical host, or the physical host disappears forcing the service to move it. If the desired task count is only 1, double it, this should give you high-availability if a single task instance needs to be moved.

Comment: Hmm does it state somewhere in AWS Fargate docs that container may be moved anywhere by Fargate automatically? If I will double containers is there a chance that Fargate will decide to move them both in same moment?

Comment: I don't know if it's in the docs but if you want a managed infra service you're usually recommended to run an HA configuration for precisely the reason that the service provider will carry out routine tasks and maintenance on underlying servers. A service like ECS with Fargate will almost certainly have been designed to minimise the chances that replicated tasks will run on the same underlying server.